# C++ Variadic template empty pack

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

I'm trying to extend std::vector with a method with the following signature:

```
template<typename... An>
tuple<An...> get();
```

I want it to return the first occurrences of specified derived class types in a vector.

I encountered some problems expanding an empty template parameter pack, however. I found this thread: [How to match empty arguments pack in variadic template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443511/how-to-match-empty-arguments-pack-in-variadic-template) so I modified my class and now it looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
class AggregationVector : public vector<T>
{
    public:
    template<typename A>
    tuple<A> getSingle()
    {
        for (auto i = vector<T>::begin(); i != vector<T>::end(); i++)
        {
            A element = dynamic_cast<A>(*i);
            if (element != nullptr) return make_tuple(element);
        }

        return make_tuple(nullptr);
    }

    template<typename A, typename... An>
    tuple<A, An...> getHelper()
    {
        return tuple_cat(getSingle<A>(), get<An...>());
    }

    template<typename... An>
    tuple<An...> get()
    {
        return getHelper<An...>();
    }

    template<>
    tuple<> get<>()
    {
        return make_tuple();
    }
};
```

Unfortunately I still get errors and I have no idea how to solve them:

```
Line 29: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class AggregationVector<T>'|
Line 30: template-id 'get<>' in declaration of primary template|
    In instantiation of 'std::tuple<_Args1 ...> AggregationVector<T>::get() [with An = {}; T = AggregationVectorTest::Base*]':|
Line 20: required from 'std::tuple<A, An ...> AggregationVector<T>::getHelper() [with A = AggregationVectorTest::DoubleDerived1*; An = {}; T = AggregationVectorTest::Base*]'|
Line 26: required from 'std::tuple<_Args1 ...> AggregationVector<T>::get() [with An = {AggregationVectorTest::DoubleDerived1*}; T = AggregationVectorTest::Base*]'|
Line 20: required from 'std::tuple<A, An ...> AggregationVector<T>::getHelper() [with A = AggregationVectorTest::Base*; An = {AggregationVectorTest::DoubleDerived1*}; T = AggregationVectorTest::Base*]'|
Line 26: required from 'std::tuple<_Args1 ...> AggregationVector<T>::get() [with An = {AggregationVectorTest::Base*, AggregationVectorTest::DoubleDerived1*}; T = AggregationVectorTest::Base*]'|
Line (this error points to line starting with "tuple<Base*, DoubleDerived1*> tup1" from example code): required from here|
Line 26: error: no matching function for call to 'AggregationVector<AggregationVectorTest::Base*>::getHelper()'|
Line 26: note: candidate is:|
Line 18: note: template<class A, class ... An> std::tuple<A, An ...> AggregationVector<T>::getHelper() [with A = A; An = {An ...}; T = AggregationVectorTest::Base*]|
Line 18: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
Line 26: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'A'|
    In member function 'std::tuple<_Args1 ...> AggregationVector<T>::get() [with An = {}; T = AggregationVectorTest::Base*]':|
Line 27: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|
```

I know that I should put s declaration of `tuple<An... method>` above `tuple<A, An...> getHelper()` but I then get an error stating the `get()` method cannot be overloaded

```
'template<class T> template<class ... An> std::tuple<_Args1 ...> AggregationVector<T>::get()' cannot be overloaded|
with 'template<class T> template<class ... An> std::tuple<_Args1 ...> AggregationVector<T>::get()'|
```

Example usage below:

```
// declaration of few polymorphic classes
class Base
{
    public:
    int Value;

    Base(int v = 0) { Value = v; }

    virtual void write()
    {
        cout << "Base " << Value << endl;
    }

    virtual ~Base();
};
class Derived1 : public Base
{
    public:
    Derived1(int v = 0) : Base::Base(v) { }

    virtual void write()
    {
        cout << "Derived1 " << Value << endl;
    }
};
class DoubleDerived1 : public Derived1
{
    public:
    DoubleDerived1(int v = 0) : Derived1::Derived1(v) { }

    virtual void write()
    {
        cout << "DoubleDerived1 " << Value << endl;
    }
};
class Derived2 : public Base
{
    public:
    Derived2(int v = 0) : Base::Base(v) { }

    virtual void write()
    {
        cout << "Derived2 " << Value << endl;
    }
};

//test implementation
Base a1(1);
Base a2(2);
Derived1 b3(3);
DoubleDerived1 bb4(4);
Derived2 c5(5);
Derived2 c6(6);

AggregationVector<Base*> vec {&a1, &a2, &b3, &bb4, &c5, &c6};

tuple<Base*, DoubleDerived1*> tup1 = vec.get<Base*, DoubleDerived1*>();
tuple<Derived1*, DoubleDerived1*, Derived2*> tup2 = vec.get<Derived1*, DoubleDerived1*, Derived2*>();

cout << "Test Tuple1 result: " << (get<0>(tup1)->Value == 1 && get<1>(tup1)->Value == 4) << endl;
cout << "Test Tuple2 result: " << (get<0>(tup2)->Value == 3 && get<1>(tup2)->Value == 4 && get<2>(tup2)->Value == 5) << endl;
```

Comment: [You can't specialize a member template of an unspecialized template class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5513109/501250). There's no reason for these functions to be members of the class anyway. They can easily be free functions.

Comment: The end of the string of variadic template should end by a `tuple<A> get<A>()`, not a empty one.

Comment: @GLCraft Both approaches work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any specializations of `get`, just

```
template<typename... An>
tuple<An...> get()
{
    return tuple_cat(getSingle<An>()...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It is exactly solution I needed. I just started dealing with variadic templates and I didn't know that this syntax is possible.