# Internal compiler error while working with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I am trying to get the product of all variadic template arguments given to a basic struct. At looks like follows:

```
template<int a, int ... as>
struct A {

    int data[doIt<a, as...>()];
};
```

And I constructed `doIt<>()` in multiple levels. I found out that this is the only way it should work. I got this solution from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443511/how-to-match-empty-arguments-pack-in-variadic-template). The code looks loke follows:

```
template<int ... is>
constexpr std::size_t doIt();

template<int i, int ... is>
constexpr std::size_t doIt_helper() {
    return i * doIt<is...>(); // this row throws the error
}

template<>
constexpr std::size_t doIt<>() {
    return 1;
}

template<int ... is>
constexpr std::size_t doIt() {
    return doIt_helper<is...>();
}
```

And when I try to compile the code I get: `internal compiler error: in instantiate_decl, at cp/pt.c:22741` and I am supposed to report the bug to gcc. But I want to make sure that I didn't do the mistake. I am compiling with `g++ -std=c++17`. And the version is `gcc version 7.5.0`. What's going on?

Comment: An internal compiler error is always a compiler bug, regardless of whether you made a mistake or not.

Comment: But should this code actually run?

Comment: According to GCC 9.1 it does. And Clang agrees too. It seems valid

Comment: As a workaround, since you are using C++17, you can just use a fold expression in lieu of the helper. `doIt` can be reduced to `return (1 * ... * is);`. This compiles fine

Comment: Thanks that works. I will report the bug now :D

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Can you please explain this syntax or a link to the documention, because this really seems like magic to me :D

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold